# Basic questionnaire input how to style questions to the left and radios to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a questionnaire and I want it to be laid out like

First question answer yes/no?.......................................................yes/no

Second question is a ridiculously long question which might........yes/no

span multiple lines so I need it to wrap nicely answer yes/no?

Third question answer yes/no?......................................................yes/no

So I'm wanting each question to span the width of the page with the question on the left hand side of the screen and the yes/no radio buttons lined up on the right hand side of the screen. If a question is a really long one I want the question to span multiple lines but still have the radio buttons on the top line to the right.

I'd also like it to scale nicely when resizing the window.

I'm not exactly great with css so I'm no having much luck getting it to work.

I have a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p35t4kj7/

but it's not working out too well for me as you will see.

Could anyone please provide some assistance here and perhaps educate me on floats or perhaps another way of doing this?

Plus the radiobuttons are actually switching places in my result.

Also not even sure my markup is great in turns of semantic markup for this. Any suggestions welcome.

```
<section>
            <span>First question answer yes/no?</span>
            <label><input type="radio" value="true" />Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="false" />No</label>
            <span>Second question is a ridiculously long question which might span multiple lines so I need it to wrap nicely answer yes/no?</span>
            <label><input type="radio" value="true" />Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="false" />No</label>
            <span>Third question answer yes/no?</span>
            <label><input type="radio" value="true" />Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="false" />No</label>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the layout you described:

1. Remove the `float: left;` from your spans-- they're already left-aligned.
2. Change your spans to divs-- otherwise, the browser will put everything on one continuous line.
3. Arrange the elements of each question in the opposite order that you want them to appear on screen (floats are kind of funny that way).
4. Set `clear: right;` on the first floated element in each question (which will be the rightmost element on screen).
5. Set `vertical-align: top;` on the input elements so that the radio button labels will line up correctly with the question text.

Here's an update of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p35t4kj7/2/).

Here's the code:

```css
label {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
label + label {clear: none;}
input {vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<section>
    <label><input type="radio" value="false" />No</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="true" />Yes</label>
    <div>First question answer yes/no?</div>
    <label><input type="radio" value="false" />No</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="true" />Yes</label>
    <div>Second question is a ridiculously long question which might span multiple lines so I need it to wrap nicely answer yes/no?</div>
    <label><input type="radio" value="false" />No</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="true" />Yes</label>
    <div>Third question answer yes/no?</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have one questionnaire here to follow you
Uses the bootstrap and css them are very top

Do you understand that throughout the term of the proposed loan you are expected to make repayments for the Borrower, and are you willing to do this.

```
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <!-- ngRepeat: input in question.inputs -->
            <label class="checkbox-inline ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="input in question.inputs">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="question.value===input.value" ng-true-value="Yes" ng-false-value="' '" name="" ng-model="question.value" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> Yes
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: input in question.inputs -->
            <label class="checkbox-inline ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="input in question.inputs">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="question.value===input.value" ng-true-value="No" ng-false-value="' '" name="" ng-model="question.value" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> No
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: input in question.inputs -->
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="/Application/QuestionSegment/Questionnaire[Identifier='1097796619440']/Question[@Code='ServicingGuarantee2']/@Response" value="">
        </div>
```

**One example**

http://codepen.io/Rabes/pen/JYwNwd

Comment: Nice. I would recommend giving the 10px margin to the first checkbox (yes) on the right, rather than the 2nd checkbox (no) to the left, because if the screen is narrow, and the boxes breaks into two lines, they will not be aligned.

Comment: Addition (more than 5 minutes passed so I can't edit) This is a bootstrap thing. My recommendation is overriding it in this case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but bootstrap isn't an option I can use